# Parse json data string store in array

Tags: c#, ios, arrays, json, xamarin

Below is parsed json data which is of type `string`.

```
  "data": [
    {
      "Company": {
        "id": "1",
        “Value": “20”,
        "companyId": "2001”,
      }
    },
    {
      "Company": {
        "id": "2",
        “value”: "20”,
        "companyId”: "2002”,
      }
    },
    {
      "Company": {
        "id": “3”,
        “value”: “30”,
        "companyId”: "2003”,
      }
    },
 ]

var parseData = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse (e.ResponseData.ToString ());
```

Convert json data string store in array,  Arraylist of stored Company Value.
this is first time dealing with Json object string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string json = @"{
      'status_code': 200,
      'status_text': 'matches found',
      'data': [{
         'company': {
           'id': '1',
           'value': '20',
           'companyId': '2001',}
         },
         {
         'company': {
           'id': '2',
           'value': '20',
           'companyId': '2002',}
         },
         {
         'company': {
           'id': '3',
           'value': '30',
           'companyId': '2003',}
         },]
       }";

JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
var ids = jObj["data"].Children()["company"]["companyId"];
var list = new List<string>();
list.AddRange(ids.Select(id => id.Value<string>()));

foreach (var item in list)
    Console.WriteLine(item);

// Outputs ->
//  2001
//  2002
//  2003
```

**Edit:**

"Everything" from companies as a list:

```
JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
var jEnum = jObj["data"].Children()["company"];

var list = jEnum.Select(company => 
    company.Values().Select(current => 
        current.Value<string>()).ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: its Say No overload method takes 0 arugments  at list.AddRange(ids.Select(id => id.Value<string>()));

Comment: Above works just fine with latest JSON.net Nuget package. Debug.

Comment: Console.WriteLine ("ids  Value {0}",ids);
 Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JEnumerable`1[[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken, Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]  its gives output.

Comment: Yes, "ids" field in this example is `JEnumerable` containing `JToken`s`. You'd want to output the values `Console.WriteLine("ids Value {0}", string.Join(",", ids.Select(id => id.Value<string>())));`

Comment: var companyid = parseData["data"].Children()["company"]["companyId"];
     Console.WriteLine("ids Value {0}", string.Join(",", companyid.Select(id => id.Value<string>())));   gives me compiler error no overload method for Value takes '0' argurments

Comment: Can't help you with that. Basic debugging should do it.

Comment: Its working!!!!  var parseData = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse (e.ResponseData.ToString ()); replace with JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

Comment: If want to add all three values to list?  Id,value and companyID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58341/discussion-between-kiran-and-mikko-viitala).